# Custom middleware that will execute on any route

Tags: node.js, express

```
router.get('/view', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else{
    //do something
  }
});

router.get('/view/abc', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else{
    //do something
  }
});
```

Imagine I have more than 20 pages in my app then it's messy every time I have to  do

```
if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
```

in every beginning routes.

How to write custom route that will run to check whether the user is login or not?

Comment: Check out http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use. It'll mount a middleware for all routes if that's what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this middleware top of your `router` code

```
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  } else {
   next(); //
  }
});
```

Comment: can I put this in app.js, use app.use instead of router.use?

Comment: yes, it ok. when you use in app.js , all route will go through this middleware